# What is the largest known prime of the form $(3^n + 1)/4$?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, exponentiation

Consider integers of the form  $(3^n + 1)/4$.

I was able to find some primes.

examples : $n = 13,23,43$ all give primes.

It seems similar to Fermat primes or Mersenne primes.

So how many of  $(3^n + 1)/4$ are prime ?

Are there infinitely many ? Or only finite ?

Since this question may be to hard ;

What is the largest known prime of the form $(3^n + 1)/4$ ?

Any sources ?

Comment: $(3^{547} + 1)/4$ is not prime. Someone claimed that but it is not.

Comment: $547$ is the prime you get when you let $n=7$ in the formula, $(3^n+1)/4$.

Comment: See [OEIS A007658](https://oeis.org/A007658).

Comment: @GerryMyerson I was aware of that.

Comment: Sure, mick, but you kept the secret well.

Comment: @JohnOmielan thanks ! I searched OEIS too but without result weird. The sequence seems asymptotic to the closest prime too $ (e - 1)^n $. hmm

Comment: @mick Does the OEIS-link already answer your question ?

Comment: We can expect infinite many primes of this form , but there are probably only finite many Fermat primes , in fact , $2^{16}+1$ is very likely the largest. But all this has of course not been proven.

Comment: @Peter yes though I wonder about the properties of that sequence. why must all index be prime ? Also it is posted as a comment not an answer so I literally cannot accept it.

Comment: Oh I see ! they must be prime because $x^{ab} + 1$ always factors. 
see also : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurifeuillean_factorization

Comment: @JohnOmielan any pattern in those primes ? like sum of squares or mod or so ?

Comment: I have not checked particularly carefully, but I don't see any obvious pattern in those primes. Regarding just the OEIS link being an "answer", I don't consider that to be true myself, which is why I posted it just as a comment only. However, if you get determine any other possibly useful information regarding those primes and/or probable primes, even if it's just a fairly rough heuristic, I suggest you consider answering your own question with those details.

Comment: @JohnOmielan that is very noble of you.  I need to think before I will answer.  at everyone ; you could still give more info than the link and get an upvoted or accepted answer ofcourse.

Comment: Iterated function for the integer values of the expression is 9y-2 leading to 9^n+(9^n-1)/(9-1)*(-2) ... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee plz clarify. And use tex. Thank you.

Comment: $\frac{3^n+1}{4}=y\implies 3^n+1=4y\implies 3^n=4y-1$ then noting only odd n create integers we multiply by 9 getting $3^{n+2}=36y-9$ which then goes to $\frac{3^{n+2}+1}{4}=\frac{36y-8}{4}=9y-2$ we then apply the iterated function...

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I see ! And by iterating we get more info about both $3^n + ..$ and $n$. Cool

Comment: $y\equiv 1\pmod 6\implies 9y-2\equiv 7 \pmod {54}$

Comment: In mod 9:  (3^(6k+1)+1)/4 is ( 4 mod 9) over 4; (3^(6k+5)+1)/4 is ( 1 mod 9) over 4

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee PLZ use tex. thanks.  Do you think you could prove the trend $(e-1)^n$ ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151149/discussion-between-roddy-macphee-and-mick).